# Escritura con retraso en textarea

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-3

Tengo un problema con en textarea.
La etiqueta en cuestión, escribe muy lento, es decir, empiezo a teclear una serie de letras rápidamente y el texto no escribe, pasan unos segundo y aparecen de repente.

Estuve probando quitar estilos y lo único que parece funcionar es hacerle un resize al área, es decir, agrando y achico el área y el problema desaparece, sin embargo, la idea es que eso no pueda agrandarse, tiene un resize: none.

Trabajo con AngularJS, pero no parece estar ahí el problema ya que he probado sin cada uno de los atributos. Uso también Bootstrap 3, pero tampoco creo que el problema esté ahí.

Lo único que cambia la velocidad es quitando los estilos, cosa que tampoco lo soluciona, sino que cuando cambio el tamaño de la caja de texto con el mouse, solo en ese momento empieza a funcionar bien.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

```css
#input_mensaje {
    max-height: 100px;
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<textarea file-dropzone="" id="input_mensaje" name="input_mensaje" code="13" ng-enter="vm.enviar()" ng-keyup="vm.controlKeyUpMessage()" ng-change="vm.validatemaxlength(formulario)" ng-style="vm.CONFIG_APP.FONT_STYLE" class="form-control mb-10 animate msd-elastic; font-emoji ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-model="vm.input_mensaje" placeholder="Enter para enviar..." ng-click="vm.showemojis(true); vm.scrollChat()" data-ng-trim="false" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 52px;">
</textarea>
```

Comment: El código que pusiste parece ir bien, el motivo de la lentitud puede ser el navegador o incluso tu dispositivo.

Comment: Gracias por responer. Sucede en todos los dispositivos - pc probados. Solo cuando quito los estilos y puedo acceder a la esquina inferior derecha y agrandar y/o achicar el tamaño de la caja, empieza a funcionar bien. Funciona de ambas formas, achicando y agrandando la caja el textarea. De hecho, si quito los estilos y no cambio el tamaño, tampoco funciona, sigue escribiendo lento. Solo al cambiar el tamaño con el mouse empieza a escribir bien.

Comment: Probablemente hay conflicto con los eventos, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de esas funciones.

Comment: @Triby dale, la edito, pero consulto antes de hacerlo: pero probé sin los atributos del textarea, sin cada uno y sin todos, y sigue sucediendo lo mismo. Tiene algo que ver?

Comment: Prueba nuevamente quitando los eventos de la etiqueta. Examina el _textarea_, si usas Firefox puedes ver los [eventos asignados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFDRG.png) ahí mismo. Si usas Chrome tendrás que ir a la [pestaña de eventos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdbvb.png). En ambos casos, revisa si hay otro evento que sea el causante del problema.

Comment: @Triby Quité todos los Event Listener, pero nada, sigue con el mismo retraso.